# Правки-предложения для сообщений, не являющихся «общими», на Мете запрещены?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, мета

При попытке поправить вопрос пользователем без репутации появляется сообщение:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но со своей репутацией могу менять чужие сообщения на мете.

[Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/260198)

Сбивает с толку формулировка. На первый взгляд, складывается ощущение, что правки постов в принципе запрещены, но дело в том, что у человека нету достаточной репутации. В английском варианте такая же проблема. Может поменяем у нас перевод?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Речь тут идёт не просто о правках, а о правках, требующих проверки другими участниками (для тех, кто ещё не набрал 2К). Это как раз скрывается за термином «правки-предложения». Можно попробовать подкорректировать этот перевод, чтобы фраза была более очевидной, однако, я бы просто хотел, чтобы данное ограничение сняли, но это уже другая история.

Искажать перевод, добавляя новые нюансы я не хочу, поэтому могу предложить для оригинальной строки

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

что-то такое (с небольшой инверсией):

> Правки, требующие проверки другими участниками, на Мете разрешены только для описания меток.

Comment: Да, так намного понятнее будет.